# Array multiplication in Java

Tags: java, arrays

Can anyone help me with the code for array multiplication?

```
arr1 = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9.
arr2 = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9.
```

I want `arr1[0]*arr2[8], arr1[1]*arr2[7]` and so on..
and their sum.
i.e `sum = (arr1[0]*arr2[8]) + (arr1[1]*arr2[7])`...
please help

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
     {           
        for(int j=9; j >=0; j--)
          {
           sum = sum + (weighting[i] * (int)iarray[j]);
          }
      }
```

I wrote the above code. But this works like `a1[1]*a2[9]+a1[1]*a2[8]+a1[1]*a2[7]...+a1[2]*a2[1]` and so on.

Answer (score 3):

Try following

```
int total = 0;

for (int i = 0;i < arr1.length;i++) {
   for(int j = arr2.length-1; j >= 0;j--) {
    total += arr1[i]*arr2[j];
   }
}
```

Java Arrays are zero index, from zero to 8 iteration.

Comment: But this works like a1[1]*a2[9]+a1[1]*a2[8]+a1[1]*a2[7]...+a1[2]*a2[1] and so on

Comment: @VineethVarma : Nope, It's working as you expected, but, both are same logically

Comment: My arr1 - {5,3,0,0,4,0,8,5,6,1,6}
My arr2 - {10,1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19}
Now I want (3x1)+(0x3)+(0x5)+(4x7)+(0x9)+(8x11)+(5x13)+(6x15)+(1x17)+ (6x19).
This code gives (1x3)+(1x0)+(1x0)+(1x4)+(1x0)+(1x8)...+(1x6)+(3x3)+(3x0)+(3x0)+(3x4)+...
My code is 
 
 for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
 {           
    for(int j=9; j >=0; j--)
    {
               sum = sum + (arr2[i] * arr1[j]);
    }
 }

Comment: @VineethVarma What you just said you want in this comment contradicts what you said you wanted in your question. Please be clear.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to step forwards and backwards at the same time e.g.

```
sum = sum + (weighting[i] * (int)iarray[iarray.length - i - 1]);
```

with only one loop (this would assume that both arrays are of the same length).

Comment: a1[1]*a2[9]+a1[1]*a2[8]+a1[1]*a2[7]...+a1[2]*a2[1] ;looks like multiply each element to each element and sum

Answer (score 0):

I think (if i understood correctly) you looking for something like this:

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 0, j = arr2.length; i <= j; i++, j--){
 sum += arr1[i] * arr2[j];
}
```

that is considering that `arr1.length` is the same as `arr2.length`

Answer (score 0):

You should try doing it this way, it's simple and functional, hope it helps:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class arraySumMult {

    private static int[] a = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    private static int[] b = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    private static int[] c = add(a, b);
    private static int[] d = multiply(a, b);

    private static int[] add(int[] a, int[] b) {
        int[] c = new int[a.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
                c[i] = a[i] + b[c.length-1-i];
        }
        return c;
    }

    private static int[] multiply(int[] a, int[] b) {
        int[] d = new int[a.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
                d[i] = a[i] * b[d.length-1-i];
        }      
        return d;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(c));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(d));
    }

}
```